# How to check if anchor URL will go to the same site (and smooth scroll, leave page otherwise)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, url, anchor

I am trying to create a bullet-proof script which is does animate scroll to an anchor with jQuery but only if the href location of the anchor is pointing to an existing anchor within my current site.

This is the script:

```
  var assConfig;

  assConfig = {
    duration: 500,
    easing: 'swing',
    complete: null
  };

  //Smooth scrolling with links
  $('a[href*=\\#]:not([href$=\\#])').on('click', function(event) {
    var hash;
    // if the anchor is on another site or subsite simply proceed with the default action
    // which will probably be leaving the site and go to ghe href location
    if (!o(event.target).attr("href")).startsWith("#") && (##### CONDITION-PART ######)) {
      return;
    }
    event.preventDefault();
    hash = '#' + $(event.target).attr("href").split("#")[1];
    if (typeof $(hash).offset() !== 'undefined') {
      $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top
      }, assConfig.duration, assConfig.easing, assConfig.complete);
    }
  });

  // Smooth scrolling when the document is loaded and ready
  $(document).ready(function() {
    if (typeof $(location.hash).offset() !== 'undefined') {
      $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(location.hash).offset().top
      }, assConfig.duration, assConfig.easing, assConfig.complete);
    }
  });
```

My question is for what to put instead of `##### CONDITION-PART ######`. If the anchor starts with a hashtag it only can be on the same page. There are anchor links like:

```
href="/?controller=info&action=site/foo#my-beautiful-anchor-target"
href="/#my-beautiful-anchor-target"
href="http://www.example.com/?foo#my-beautiful-anchor-target"
```

Sometimes they may mean the same site though they are different like:

```
href="http://www.example.com/?foo#my-beautiful-anchor-target"
href="/?foo#my-beautiful-anchor-target"
href="?foo#my-beatiful-anchor-target"
```

So what is the best way to detect if between `$(event.target).href` and `window.location.href` is a page reload?

Comment: I would try: `event.target.pathname !== window.location.pathname || event.target.hostname !== window.location.hostname` (+ possibly protocol)

Comment: @bigless Seems like quite a good approach. I have found some similar solution: https://teamtreehouse.com/community/scroll-to-in-jquery-anyone-got-any-advice . Does pathname contain the GET-string?

Comment: I dont think so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I have ended up with:

```
event.target.pathname !== window.location.pathname 
|| event.target.hostname !== window.location.hostname 
|| event.target.protocol !== window.location.protocol 
|| event.target.search !== window.location.search
```

Final complete solution:

```
var assConfig = {
    duration: 500,
    easing: 'swing',
    complete: null
};

//Smooth scrolling with links
$('a[href*=\\#]:not([href$=\\#])').on('click', function (event) {
    var hash;
    if (event.target.pathname !== window.location.pathname || event.target.hostname !== window.location.hostname || event.target.protocol !== window.location.protocol || event.target.search !== window.location.search) {
        return;
    }
    event.preventDefault();
    hash = '#' + $(event.target).attr("href").split("#")[1];
    if (typeof $(hash).offset() !== 'undefined') {
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top
        }, assConfig.duration, assConfig.easing, assConfig.complete);
    } else {
        console.log("Note: Scrolling to the anchor ist not possible as the anchor does not exist.");
    }
});

// Smooth scrolling when the document is loaded and ready
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (typeof $(location.hash).offset() !== 'undefined') {
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(location.hash).offset().top
        }, assConfig.duration, assConfig.easing, assConfig.complete);
    } else {
        console.log("Note: Scrolling to the anchor ist not possible as the anchor does not exist.");
    }
});
```